# How to uninstall shorewall completely from Ubuntu

Tags: networking, firewall, linux-networking, ubuntu-16.04, shorewall

I noticed on my some servers shorewall service is installed but it's not running.I want to uninstall it.

I executed the command `sudo systemctl status shorewall` to check status of shorewall and got the below output.

```
shorewall.service - Shorewall IPv4 firewall
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/shorewall.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: inactive (dead)
```

Then I executed `sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove shorewall` command to uninstall the shorewall. After uninstalling it, I checked the status of shorewall with this command again `sudo systemctl status shorewall` then It' giving output like below.

```
shorewall.service
Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
Active: inactive (dead)
Jul 08 20:24:23 ip-10-10-10-10 systemd[1]: Stopped Shorewall IPv4 firewall.
```

Can anyone confirm please that is shorewall uninstalled successfully?, why is it giving the output like this?

Answer (score 0):

The output of `systemctl status shorewall` indicates that you successfully removed it from your computer. However, the log entries remain from when it was previously installed. The log entries are not deleted.

Comment: Just now I deleted the shorewall logs files like ```shorewall-init.log*``` from ```/var/log/```. After that I executed the status command but it showing same output as I mentioned previously. If shorewall is uninstalled completely then status command ```sudo systemctl status shorewall``` should show the output something like this ```shorewall is not found``` or ```shorewall services is unknown```.

Comment: That is what it said!